# Member 'Camera.main' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a Type name instead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my line of code:

```
GetComponent<Camera>().main.transform.position.y = StaticCameraY;
```

This is the error that I get and I am not sure how to solve it:

> Member 'Camera.main' cannot be accessed with an instance reference;
>   qualify it with a Type name instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the main camera like :

```
Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.position, StaticCamera.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z);
```

For the following reasons:
 - When using GetComponent to get a camera on your current gameObject, you have to use it like `Camera cam = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>();`With no need to call it main. You do have to pass the type of component you are getting in `<>` though.
- The main camera can be found with Camera.main with no GetComponent involved.
- You can't set individual elements of transform.position. You have to set the whole Vector3. To do this we pass the current transform.position.x and transform.position.z and update only the y because that's the one you care about changing.

Hope that helped.